# document.createElement() for h4 tag inside header tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a source code written in HTML5:

```
<header>
     <h4>Something...</h4>
</header>
```

If I am right, HTML5 is supported in IE from version IE9. When I have IE8 for example, I have found a solution, how to use HTML5. I add a simple JavaScript code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.createElement('header');
</script>
```

But how can I do the same for h4 tag inside the header?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10 secs with google got http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: @EdHeal—please don't reference [*W3Schools*](http://www.w3fools.com). Better to reference [*W3C DOM Core*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) and [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) for examples, or [*MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535934(v=vs.85).aspx) where appropriate.

Comment: No, I didn't mean this. I do not need to append a new one. I have a h4 tag, and I need to somehow make it look like in Google Chrome, Firefox, or probably IE9. So for example the h4 text is rotated, but the IE8 shows it without roation.

Comment: Agreed, w3schools more like w3fools

Comment: @adamhala007 — Err… it sounds like your question is about how to make IE8 support CSS transforms, not how to get it to recognise the `h4` element (which it already does).

Comment: I am afraid, you are right, sorry. I am new in creating Webpages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a simple `.appendChild()` on the `header` element you just created, like this:

```
var header = document.createElement("header"),
    h4 = document.createElement("h4");

h4.textContent = "something";
header.appendChild(h4);
document.body.appendChild(header);
```

The above code will append the `header` element to the `body` of your document, like this:

```
<body>
    <header>
         <h4>something</h4>
    </header>
</body>
```